# Ruby Converting a string of 8-Bit ASCII to 6-Bit ASCII

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm new to ruby and got a very specific problem when working with chars and bits. I need to convert a string of 8 characters (encoded in 8-Bit ASCII) to a string of 8 characters (encoded in 6-Bit ASCII). The input ist 8x8Bit=64Bit long and the output should be 8x6Bit=48Bit long. The Conversion is quiet easy. On every Character erase the first 2 bits, e.g. 1001 0110 -> 01 0110.

For example: The String `"UAL    "` (ASCII dual: 0101 0101 0100 0001 0100 1100) will be converted to 0101 0100 0001 0011 00 rest filled with 0 (ASCII dual).

Does ruby support this kind of conversion? If not, what is the best approach to do so without many dependencies?

To set the problem in reference: I need to modify the Bytes of a ASTERIX CAT62 (https://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/content/documents/nm/asterix/cat062p9ed118.pdf) UDP Packet. The field im interested in is I062/380 Subfield 2 (in the document on page 79). There you can see, that the ASCII encoding needs to be in 6-Bit.

**EDT: Solution**

After hours of work i finally got to the right solution.

```
characters = "UAL     ".bytes
output_int = 0
shifter = 48
characters.each do |character|
  shifter -= 6
  output_int += (character & 0b00111111) << shifter #Convert to 6-Bit ASCII
end
hex_values = [
  (output_int >> 40) & 0b11111111,
  (output_int >> 32) & 0b11111111,
  (output_int >> 24) & 0b11111111,
  (output_int >> 16) & 0b11111111,
  (output_int >> 8) & 0b11111111,
  (output_int >> 0) & 0b11111111
]
output = ""
hex_values.each do |hex_value|
  output += [hex_value].pack("C")
end
```

Comment: Ruby does not have a 6bit ASCII encoding which is really quite rare. You can check the available encodings with `Encoding.name_list`.

Comment: `U` is 01010101 in binary (00101010 would be `*`). However, can you give an example 8 byte input string and the expected 6 byte output string?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the spec. I assume that you already did the work to find all the relevant information in that 140 page document? Please add those parts to the question, in particular how the encoding works in detail. If possible, provide a simple example.

Comment: _"rest filled with 0"_ – why though? A space character is 00100000 binary, so its last 6 bits are 100000, not 000000. Is space treated differently? _"i need output_int to substitute on the right bytes"_ – but what are the right bytes? Show the expected output for `"UAL"` or `"UAL     "` as a string, please.